# Aitken interpolation of a polynomial?

Tags: interpolation

How I can approximate a polynomial using [Aitken's scheme](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AitkenInterpolation.html) using two nodes for the interpolation?

```
[HASKELL]
x1 = 2;
x2 = 3;
x3 = 4;
x4 = 5;

f1 = 2;
f2 = 3;
f3 = 12;
f4 = 147;

coefficientAitken[Xi_, Xinext_, Yi_, Yinext_] := 
  Collect[1/(Xinext - Xi)*Det[{{Yi, Xi - x}, {Yinext, Xinext - x}}], 
   x];

(*c1 = coefficientAitken[2,3,2,3];
c2 = coefficientAitken[3,4,3,12];
c2 = coefficientAitken[4,5,12,147];*)

LnTwoNodes = coefficientAitken[x1, x2, f1, f2];
[/HASKELL]
```

Comment: Almost none of these terms (e.g., "polymon") are defined or can be found within Mathematica documentation.

Comment: Here's an article about implementing Aitken's with Mathematica. Warning, bad code ahead: http://www.ajournal.co.uk/pdfs/BSvolume7%281%29/BSVol.7%20%281%29%20Article%202.pdf

Comment: @belisarius prominent use of `Print` there for sure.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 6):

This is Aitken's recursive algorithm:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
f[x_] := Exp[x]
(x[#] = #) & /@ Range@10;

p[i_, 1][_] := f[x[i]];
p[i_, k_][xs_] := 1/(x[i] - x[k-1]) Det[{{p[k-1,k-1][xs], x[k-1] - xs},
                                         {p[i, k-1] [xs], x[i]   - xs}}]

p[2, 2][x]
(* 2 E - E^2 - E x + E^2 x *)

r = p[9,9][x]
Plot[r, {x, 1, 9}, Epilog -> Point@Table[{x, Exp[x]}, {x, 1, 10}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I used this definition :

[image: Mathematica graphics]

from [here](http://www.ajournal.co.uk/pdfs/BSvolume7%281%29/BSVol.7%20%281%29%20Article%202.pdf). Warning: there is code in that article, but you'd better ignore it.

Edit:

After reading your self-answer I saw that you want to interpolate points, not functions.
The following is a general solution for that. Posting with your own data as well:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
{xi, fi} = {{2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 12, 147}}
p[i_, 1][_] := fi[[i]];
p[i_, k_][xs_] := 1/(xi[[i]] - xi[[k - 1]]) 
                  Det[{{p[k - 1, k - 1][xs], xi[[k - 1]] - xs}, {p[i, k - 1][xs], xi[[i]] - xs}}]

p[4, 4][x]

(* -448 + (1477 x)/3 - 173 x^2 + (59 x^3)/3 *)
```

As you can see, it's terser than your code because the recursive step is already included in the function definition, while you are doing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for my English. I did it myself.

```
x1 = 2;
x2 = 3;
x3 = 4;
x4 = 5;

f1 = 2;
f2 = 3;
f3 = 12;
f4 = 147;

Determinant[a11_, a12_, a21_, a22_] := (a11*a22) - (a12*a21);

LnTwoNodes = coefficientAitken[x1, x2, f1, f2];
polynomAitken[Xi_, Xinext_, Yi_, Yinext_] := 
  Collect[(1/(Xinext - Xi))*
    Determinant[Yi, Xi - x, Yinext, Xinext - x], x];

LOne1 = polynomAitken[x1, x2, f1, f2]
LOne2 = polynomAitken[x2, x3, f2, f3]
LOne3 = polynomAitken[x3, x4, f3, f4]

LTwo1 = polynomAitken[x1, x3, LOne1, LOne2]
LTwo2 = polynomAitken[x2, x4, LOne2, LOne3]

Final = polynomAitken[x1, x4, LTwo1, LTwo2]
```

Comment: You did what yourself? Ain't no recursion here! And why would you reinvent `Det[]`? You should really consider the solution of @belisarius.